# How to change Vue component after axios post method

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using Laravel 8 and Vue 3
I have a SessionComponent.vue and there's is a button on it, and I would like when I click on that button, which is going trigger an axios post method, to have my StudentComponent.vue displaying.

I tried to use vue-router, but it doesn't work for me I have a lot of issue with it so I would like to know if there is an other options to do a simple link like that.

```
    /*This is My session Component*/

    <template>
        <h1 class="title_session">Choose or create a session</h1>
        <select id="session" name="session" @blur.prevent="getSessionName($event)">
            <option disabled selected value="">Select a session</option>
            <option v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id">{{ card.session }}</option>
        </select>

        <label for="createSession">Create a new session</label>
        <input id="createSession" ref="session" type="text" >

    <!--    <router-link to="/student">Test</router-link>

        <router-view></router-view>-->

    </template>

    <script>
    const AXIOS = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
    export default {
        AXIOS: AXIOS,
        name: "Session.vue",
        data() {
            return {
                cards: {},
                sessionName: '',
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getSession() {
                axios.get(AXIOS + 'session')
                    .then(response => this.cards = response.data)
                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
            },
            createSession() {
                this.sessionName = this.$refs.session.value;
                console.log(this.sessionName)
                axios.post(AXIOS + 'session', {
                    sessionName: this.sessionName
                })
                    .then(response => this.sessionName = response.data)
                    .catch(error => console.log(error))
            },

            getSessionName(event) {
                this.sessionName = event.target.value;
                console.log(this.sessionName)
                axios.post(AXIOS + 'session', {
                    sessionName: this.sessionName
                })
                    .then(response => this.sessionName = response.data)
                    .catch(error => console.log(error))
            },
        },

        mounted() {
            console.log("How many time")
        },

        created() {
            this.getSession()
        },
        updated() {
            this.getSession()
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please post some code as well. Why couldn't you just use `v-if` to hide the component until the button was pressed?

Comment: It seems like a good idea, i'am gonna update my post so you can see my code

Comment: Your code does not show how `StudentComponent` fits into all this... well you can [$emit](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html) to let the parent component know something happened and let it display the component.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Thanks for your help I'll take a look at those solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear.
However if you want your SessionComponent to display a certain data after a button click.
In your SessionComponent.vue

```
<!--- your html ----->
<div v-if="displayData"> {dataToDisplay} </div>
<!--- your html ----->
<button @click="ApiCall"> Display Data button </button>
<!--- your html ----->
```

Inside your script methods

```
Apicall () {
  yourApiCal((result) => {
  // do what you want with result and modify dataToDisplay accordingly
     this.displayData = true;
})
}
```

make sure to have displayData to equal false by default.